# Do we use 'work in' or 'at' a gas station?

Tags: prepositions, usage

Which one is correct?

> *Wind up working **in** a gas station* (song name by Frank Zappa)

or

> *He knew that Old Joe didn’t work **at** the gas station anymore*
>   (an example from Grammar textbook.)

Or may both variants be acceptable?

Comment: in- inside the boundaries of gas station. at- at a specific location, i.e gas station. Both will work.

Answer (score 1):

The word *work* is tricky there.

The **general** answer is - **yes,** both are correct.

But if you look it microscopically, it *can* be different.

A good example on [WikiAnswer](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Which_is_correct_English_-working_at_or_working_in?#slide=1) (and that's what I practice too!) says...

> Use *work at* with a company's or firm's name - I work *at IBM.* 
>   Use *work in* with a genre/field that company is in - I work *in a hardware company.*

Comment: The answer at wikianswers.com is given by a user like you and me. Can it be used as a source to validate/support one's answer?

Comment: @SandeepDhamija True but then we always apply our brain and logically think whether it's worth quoting as a source. Personally, I liked it (as I practice it!). This is not utterly wrong as well, is it?

Comment: no it isn't. It's fine :)

Comment: I wonder if that's Indian English usage?  I, personally, work at a health care company, in an office building.

Comment: Well, if it were about *company* I would not ask. What I'm asking about is can I use both of these prepositions in the *same* context? When the gas station is just a gas station, with no speculations about "location", "boundaries" etc ( obviously any location has boundaries).

Comment: @Max I said it in my very first sentence - **you can**. The latter content is additional but might be a useful piece of information.